# Как правильно сделать переключатели в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой

вот структура бд

id

title

all - (по умолчанию 0)

Вот хочу сделать переключатель стать на сайте Типа "предыдущая статья" и "следующая статья".

Сейчас само url страницы статьи выглядит вот так site.ru/f?id=1 (то есть вывожу по id через get);

Я переключатели сделал таким образом, пример

```
<a href="f?=<?php echo $r['id'] + 1"> Следующая страница</a>

<a href="f?=<?php echo $r['id'] - 1"> Предыдущая страница</a>
```

Я хочу выводить например страницы с примечанием если all = 1, то переключатели будут листать все статьи по id.

ну например есть статьи

id = 1 и all = 0

id = 2 и all = 0

id = 3 и all = 1

id = 4 и all = 1

id = 5 и all = 0

То есть хочу чтоб переключатели при условии all = 1 переключали только на статьи где стоит all =1

Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: Надо при отображении статьи сразу делать запрос следующую/предыдущую.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос по идее типа такого

```
select * from table where `id` = 3
```

Далее проверяем, есть ли у этой статьи all = 1, если есть - то делаем еще 2 запроса.

Для следующей

```
select id from table where id = (select min(id) from table where id > 3)
```

Для прошлой

```
select id from table where id = (select max(id) from table where id < 3)
```